# How to resolve/finalize an Ivy file (descriptor) without downloading any artifacts?

Tags: ivy

Using Ivy, I'd like to run the resolve task to finalize my ivy file dependency versions, but not download artifacts.

I see that there is a type attribute on the resolve task that lets us filter for artifacts of a certain type:

[Resolve Task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ivy resolve task by itself does not finalize the Ivy descriptor file.

The Ivy [Deliver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/deliver.html) task finalizes the Ivy descriptor file.

Running the resolve task with a blank string for the type atttribute resolves but prevents downloading any artifact dependencies:

```
<ivy:resolve type=""/>
```

For Deliver to correctly finalize the Ivy descriptor file, I must call the Resolve task as a dependency of the Deliver task (using Ant):

```
<target name="deliver" depends="resolve">
   <ivy:deliver/>
</target>
<target name="resolve">
   <ivy:resolve/>
</target>
```

Calling the Resolve and Deliver tasks as separate executions of Ant won't work.